# method or data member not found for list method

Tags: vba

I want to transfer data drom `ListBox` to `TextBox` using click event and I am getting error of method or data?

> `SearchList.List(i)` (error for `.List(i)`)

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To SearchList.ListCount - 1
   Textbox.Value = Textbox.Value & SearchList.List(i) & vbNewLine
Next
```

Comment: `Textbox.Text` should work (not `.Value`)

Comment: same problem not solved

Comment: What kinds of list and text boxes are these? And where are the located? Are we dealing with a UserForm? Controls on a document surface? If the latter, what kind of document (which application)? Which line of code is causing the error? Is htat really the exact error message - it looks very... odd?

Comment: i am working on access form Searchbox refereing to listbox.i want to copy data from from listbox to textbox by click event. (.List(i)) method not found